# Writing some 301 rules for subdomain only

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to write some 301 rules for some old backlinks, these would be placed in *.htaccess* within http://subdomain.domain.com (not in root *.htaccess* of domain.com).

Here are a some types of redirects I'd like to set up, first specific rules followed by a catch-all fallback. I would appreciate some advice on writing correct RewriteCond rules for this kind of logic, all of these have a specific final URL to redirect to:

- A) request contains **location=uae**
  = 301 to "http://www.domain.com/subfolder/sub2/sub3" (match pattern, redirect all to a **specific** final URL, no trailing slash).
- B) request contains **searchTerms=someterm1**
  = 301 to "http://www.domain.com/subfolder2/program/url" (again match a paticular pattern and redirect all matches to a specific final URL with no trailing slash).
- C) request contains **reqGK=755381** or **reqGK=795971** 
  = 301 to "http://www.domain.com/another/specific/url" ... this RewriteCond would have a part of the regex that looks like *reqGK=(755381|795971)* i believe but i'm not totally sure.
- D) [**FALLBACK / CATCHALL** for all requests not already matched by A-C above] ANY other request at all = 301 to "http://www.domain.com/specific/url/forfallback" (a final specific URL reference that gets sent all the remaining HTTP requests from *subdomain.domain.com*).

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \blocation=uae\b
RewriteRule ^.*$            http://www.domain.com/subfolder/sub2/sub3 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bsearchTerms=someterm1\b
RewriteRule ^.*$            http://www.domain.com/subfolder2/program/url [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \breqGK=(755381|795971)\b
RewriteRule ^.*$            http://www.domain.com/another/specific/url [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^.*$            http://www.domain.com/specific/url/forfallback [L,R=301]
```